# Prover9 cannot find correct solution

Tags: boolean-expression, theorem-proving, data-representation

I have tried to use prover9 to prove the very simple statement which is obvious for a human, but I fortunately cannot get it working. I have the following scenario:

```
% Three boys - Dan, Louise and Tom have t-shirts in three diffrent colors
% (white, yellow and green) and with three different patterns: (giraffe, camel and
% panda). Dan has the t-shirt with giraffe, Louise has the yelow one and Tom has
% not the white t-shirt. The boy with the yellow one has not the one with camel
% pattern. Task:
% Represent exercise with classical boolean statements and using 
% resolution algorithm answer the question: "who has the t-shirt with the camel pattern?"

formulas(sos).
%      (pattern(Dan, Giraffe) & pattern(Louise, Panda) & pattern(Tom, Camel))
%    | (pattern(Dan, Giraffe) & pattern(Louise, Camel) & pattern(Tom, Panda))
%    | (pattern(Dan, Panda) & pattern(Louise,Giraffe) & pattern(Tom, Camel))
%    | (pattern(Dan, Panda) & pattern(Louise, Camel) & pattern(Tom, Giraffe))
%    | (pattern(Dan, Camel) & pattern(Louise, Panda) & pattern(Tom, Giraffe))
%    | (pattern(Dan, Camel) & pattern(Louise, Giraffe) & pattern(Tom, Panda)).
    % This does not works, unfortunately

      (pattern(Dan, Giraffe) & pattern(Louise, Panda) & pattern(Tom, Camel))
    | (pattern(Dan, Giraffe) & pattern(Louise, Camel) & pattern(Tom, Panda)).
    % This works

      (color(Dan, White) & color(Louise, Yellow) & color(Tom, Green))
    | (color(Dan, White) & color(Louise, Green) & color(Tom, Yellow))
    | (color(Dan, Yellow) & color(Louise,White) & color(Tom, Green))
    | (color(Dan, Yellow) & color(Louise, Green) & color(Tom, White))
    | (color(Dan, Green) & color(Louise, Yellow) & color(Tom, White))
    | (color(Dan, Green) & color(Louise, White) & color(Tom, Yellow)).

    pattern(Dan, Giraffe).
    color(Louise, Yellow).

    -color(Tom,White).
    all x (color(x,Yellow) -> -pattern(x,Camel)).
end_of_list.

formulas(goals).
    pattern(Tom,Camel). % Our solution
    % pattern(Louise, Panda).
end_of_list.
```

1. and 2. formula is the writing down all possibilities with no constraints - simple permutation 3! (even we know that Dan has giraffe and we could write down 2 possibilities). It should not modify the problem adding additional or statements should not cut off our existing proof, however it makes in my current solution. 3. statement (pattern(Dan, Girrafe) de facto cuts off unnecessary possibilities (without which program finds the correct solution).

I have no idea, whether I use badly prover9 or just simply overlooked something in my problem (or in its representation in classical boolean statements). What could I do wrong?

Comment: Have you used Mace4 to search for a counter-example? If it finds one (when you don't expect it), that's often because you've not represented the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add a statement which says that a particular animal can only be on one t-shirt:
    all x (pattern (Dan, x) -> (- pattern(Tom, x) & -pattern (Louise, x))).

This captures what we do when we reason this out: Dan has the giraffe and Louise does not have the camel. Since Louise cannot also have the giraffe, Louise must have the panda.

Once this is added, your first set of statements and the info from the problem will lead to a proof.

The reason that things worked with the second formulation of the constraints (but not with the first) is that there are fewer options. Resolution changes statements to conjunctive normal form. The given statement is of the form (A & B & C) | (A & D & E). Applying the distributive law leads to 9 separate statements: A | A, A | D, A | E, B | A, B | D, B | E, C | A, C | D, C | E.  Each of these only has two parts. Once -pattern(Louise, Camel) is derived resolution can reduce some of these statements to a single primitive and complete the proof.

The first formulation of the constraints has more options - and changing it to conjunctive normal form leads to statements such as pattern(Dan,Giraffe) | pattern(Dan,Panda) | pattern(Louise,Panda) | pattern(Louise,Giraffe).

```
% Saved by Prover9-Mace4 Version 0.5, December 2007.

set(ignore_option_dependencies). % GUI handles dependencies

if(Prover9). % Options for Prover9   assign(max_seconds, 60).
end_if.

if(Mace4).   % Options for Mace4   assign(max_seconds, 60). end_if.

formulas(assumptions).

% Three boys - Dan, Louise and Tom have t-shirts in three different colors 
% (white, yellow and green) and with three different patterns: (giraffe, camel and 
% panda). Dan has the t-shirt with giraffe, Louise has the yellow one and Tom has 
% not the white t-shirt. The boy with the yellow one has not the one with camel 
% pattern. Task: 
% Represent exercise with classical boolean statements and using  
% resolution algorithm answer the question: "who has the t-shirt with the camel pattern?" 

%formulas(sos).
     (pattern(Dan, Giraffe) & pattern(Louise, Panda) & pattern(Tom, Camel))
    | (pattern(Dan, Giraffe) & pattern(Louise, Camel) & pattern(Tom, Panda))
    | (pattern(Dan, Panda) & pattern(Louise,Giraffe) & pattern(Tom, Camel))
    | (pattern(Dan, Panda) & pattern(Louise, Camel) & pattern(Tom, Giraffe))
    | (pattern(Dan, Camel) & pattern(Louise, Panda) & pattern(Tom, Giraffe))
    | (pattern(Dan, Camel) & pattern(Louise, Giraffe) & pattern(Tom, Panda)).
    % The above now works

      (color(Dan, White) & color(Louise, Yellow) & color(Tom, Green))
    | (color(Dan, White) & color(Louise, Green) & color(Tom, Yellow))
    | (color(Dan, Yellow) & color(Louise,White) & color(Tom, Green))
    | (color(Dan, Yellow) & color(Louise, Green) & color(Tom, White))
    | (color(Dan, Green) & color(Louise, Yellow) & color(Tom, White))
    | (color(Dan, Green) & color(Louise, White) & color(Tom, Yellow)).

    pattern(Dan, Giraffe).
    color(Louise, Yellow).

    -color(Tom,White).
    all x (color(x,Yellow) -> -pattern(x,Camel)).

   % Dan has the giraffe and Louise does NOT have the camel; therefore Louise     
   % has the Panda (because Louise cannot also have the giraffe)    
   % A pattern on Dan's t-shirt cannot be on Tom's or Louise's t-shirt
    all x (pattern (Dan, x) -> (- pattern(Tom, x) & -pattern (Louise, x))).

end_of_list.

formulas(goals).

pattern(Tom, Camel).

end_of_list.
```